# Event that combines Enter and Leave events (while Focused)

Tags: c#, winforms

Is there any event that executes a function as long as some control(say button) is focused?

I want to change appearance of buttons in my form when they have focus/cursor on them.

For now I've done it with Enter and Leave events ( change backcolor on Enter event and revert it to normal on Leave).
But is there some single event that can do it like, whileFocused?

Answer (score 0):

You can attach the same event handler to both events (`Enter` and `Leave`) and then write:

```cs
private void button1_EnterOrLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    button1.BackColor = button1.Focused ? Color.White : Color.Yellow;
}
```

E.g. write this method first, compile, and then select this handler for the two events in the properties box:
[image]

Note that the `Focused` property is set only **after** this event handler is run. Therefore, you must swap the two colors.

We can improve on this and use the same event handler for several controls of any type. To do this, we use the `sender` which is the control who triggered the event and cast it to `Control`:

```cs
private void Control_EnterOrLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var control = (Control)sender;
    control.BackColor = control.Focused ? Color.White : Color.Yellow;
}
```

You can select all controls together and then assign this event handler to the `Enter` and `Leave` events at once.

---

Another solution is to create your own control. Here, for example a Button:

```cs
public class FocusButton : Button
{
    public Color FocusColor { get; set; } = Color.Yellow;

    private Color _normalColor = SystemColors.Control;
    private bool _useStyle = true;

    protected override void OnEnter(EventArgs e)
    {
        _normalColor = BackColor;
        _useStyle = UseVisualStyleBackColor;
        BackColor = FocusColor;
        base.OnEnter(e);
    }

    protected override void OnLeave(EventArgs e)
    {
        BackColor = _normalColor;
        UseVisualStyleBackColor = _useStyle;
        base.OnLeave(e);
    }
}
```

After compiling this code for the first time, you will see this button appear in the Toolbox where it is ready to be dragged and dropped to a Form.

The `FocusColor` will appear in the properties window where you can set it easily.

Note that `UseVisualStyleBackColor` also affects the background color and since setting the background color sets this property to `False` I also restore it in the `Leave` event.

Also note that we don't subscribe to the event. Instead, we override the corresponding `On...` methods. This is the way to handle events in overridden controls. This is also true for the Form events which derived from `Form` which in turn derives from `Control`. E.g., you can override `OnLoad` instead of subscribing to the `Load` event. Since these `On...` methods are protected, you must subscribe to the events when needed from another class, e.g., when using a Button Click in the Form code.

---

**Efficiency**

Memory Consumption:

- The first solution subscribes to two events and will use a little bit of memory for each control for this. Also, the code will be duplicated in each Form.
- The custom button class does not add fields to the button. Therefore, its memory consumption will be the same as for the original `Button`. The code will not be copied. Even if you have 100 such custom buttons, the code will exist only once.
- Both solutions will use very little memory but the second solution will consume slightly less.

Run Speed:

- Both solutions run very little code and are about equally fast.

Compile Time:

- A few dozens of lines of code have no noticeable impact. The compile and build times (Visual Studio) have been improved a lot in the recent years.

Usage efficiency:

- The first solution must be implemented explicitly for every form and every button;however, with only a small effort.
- With the custom button solution, the button behave as expected out-of-the-box. This must be implemented for every required type of Control.

Bottom line: The memory consumption and the compile and run speed are good for both solutions and the differences do barely matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
Both the ways satisfy my need(I was kind of using the first way before, same func. for enter and leave).
Which approach do you think is considered proper or increases efficiency/ reduce compile time, etc. ? 
If both are equally efficient or almost equally efficient, then i'd like to keep it as it is(1st approach).

Comment: Efficiency is not an issue here. It's more a matter of simplicity in usage. The first approach is easy, works for all control types, but must be setup repeatedly on all the forms. The second approach has the advantage that the button has this functionality built-in, with no further action required from your part, but has the disadvantage that you must implement it for all control types where you need it.